# Nagiosgraph mouseover fails

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I have setup **Nagios 4** together with **Nagiosgraph** and they are both working perfect.

However the javascript **Mouseover** effect does not work.

I have copied the following line in ../nagios/share/ssi/common-header.ssi as mentioned in Nagiosgraph Documentation and **it is the only line**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/nagiosgraph/nagiosgraph.js"></script>
```

However when I make a Mouseover effect over the Nagiosgraph icon I get the following error in apache error.log:

```
[Thu Nov 27 11:48:21 2014] [error]  ../nagios/share/ssi/common-header.ssi: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
[Thu Nov 27 11:48:21 2014] [error]  ../nagios/share/ssi/common-header.ssi: line 1: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/nagiosgraph/nagiosgraph.js"></script>'
```

Are there any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to resolve the issue.
The following steps should be followed:

1. The `../nagios/share/ssi/common-header.ssi` file should be in shell script format:

   ```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/nagios/nagiosgraph.js\"></script>"
   ```
2. Also the file `../nagios/share/ssi/common-header.ssi` should be readable and executable, which means I had to run the following command:

   ```
   chmod a+rx common-header.ssi
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for me so it doesn't look like a universal solution

Answer (score -1):

1. The first step to installing nagiosgraph, is to download the debian package and install it. The package can be downloaded via WGET, here:

a.       http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/downloads.sourceforge.net/n/na/nagiosgraph/nagiosgraph/1.4.4/nagiosgraph-1.4.4-2.deb

2. Once you’ve run wget and have the debian installation file on your Alienvault system, you need to install it with the following command:

a.       dpkg –i nagiosgraph-1.4.4-2.deb

3. The final piece of the install is to modify the file, /etc/nagios3/conf.d/generic-service_nagios2.cfg. In this file, you need to a the following line just above the register line.

a.       action_url /nagiosgraph/cgi-bin/show.cgi?host=$HOSTNAME$&service=$SERVICEDESC$' onMouseOver='showGraphPopup(this)' onMouseOut='hideGraphPopup()' rel='/nagiosgraph/cgi-bin/showgraph.cgi?host=$HOSTNAME$&service=$SERVICEDESC$&period=week&rrdopts=-w+450+-j

```
  4.    After that, you need to add the nagiosgraph javascript file to the nagios header with the following command:
              a.    cp /usr/share/nagiosgraph/examples/nagiosgraph.ssi /usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/ssi/common-header.ssi
```

5.       Once you’re done modifying the file, you simple restart nagios3 and apache2 with the following commands:

a.       service nagios3 restart

b.    service apache2 restart

Comment: As mentioned in the question NagiosGraph has been installed and is working perfectly. Could you please help with the MouseOver issue I have?